# How can i prevent CMD+L from lagging in full screen mode in Safari

Tags: macos, safari, keybindings

My first question here. I tried Safari and i honestly like it very much, it is much more faster than Google chrome. I would like to use it in full screen mode, with `Always Show Toolbar in Full Screen` toggled off.
I would like to jump to search box with `Cmd+L`, but the pop up window is cut off as you can see in printscreen. I can't see the input box.  Where can i submit bug report? Am i doing something wrong? This looks like basic behaviour to me...

Safari: Version 14.1.1 (16611.2.7.1.4)
MacOS: Big Sur 11.4 (M1 machine)

[image]

Comment: Just to note it doesn't do this in Safari 14.1 on Mojave in fullscreen. Cmd/L pops the URL/search bar as it should.

Answer (score 0):

Start typing and input field will be visible.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Yeah that removes the window with quick access and i am able to see the input field
However i would like to fix this problem, is there any way to submit issue to Apple?

Comment: File feedback at: https://www.apple.com/feedback/

Comment: What kind of 'issue'? For me personally this is expected but not very intuitive behavior. This happens only when toolbar is hidden in full screen which is signalling that you don't need immediate access to items on toolbar, including input field.

Comment: @AivarPaalberg The window itself is cutoff, this couldn't possibly be desired behaviour
It doesn't break the experience, it is more like visual bug.
I already filled the report, could you do the same to emphasise this problem?